# Batch rename(regex) according to number pattern

Tags: regex, batch-rename

I have a bunch of file on openload that i would like to rename using the batch rename feature but i'm new to it and i don't really know where to start from. I tried looking up some previous asked questions but couldn't find anything that could help.

The file are named this way:

Filename001suffix

Filename002suffix

Filename003suffix

Filename004suffix

Filename005suffix and so on....

I would like to rename them to

FN001

FN002

FN003

FN004

FN005 and so on.....

So i would like to put a suffix and then add a number according to the order in which it is displayed in the File manager, increasing each by 1.
How can i do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: windows, does it make any difference on openload.co?

Comment: along with OS it depends on how do you rename those files. P.S. it's an easy task for Linux OS

Answer (score 0):

i have a ideas, hope to help you.

1. Read the file name ex: document001dix
2. Use regex: '^[A-z]+(\d+)[A-z]', we get a group var x = (\d+)=>001. purpose get group numbers.
3. Then rename file. 'FN' + x